# Is there any reason why the Community user wouldn't bump a question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, unanswered-questions, community-user, bump

I have two unanswered questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110516/resharper-running-all-tests-when-only-a-single-one-is-selected), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550027/is-there-any-way-to-stop-wmd-editor-from-wrapping-text-area-contents-in-a-p-tag)).

Question 1 has one answer, 74 views, no upvotes, and multiple comments. This question was asked back in July, and it is being bumped by the Community user fairly often.

Question 2 has 19 views, no upvotes, no comments, no answers and has never once been bumped.

Is there a reason for this? Unless I'm mistaken, both questions fit the criteria for being unanswered.

Comment: Also note, I'm not complaining that my questions aren't receiving any answers. I know there are other ways to get attention to my questions, I'm just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: I told you not to make the community user mad.  Now see what you've done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a lot of unanswered questions; this is like asking "why haven't I won the lottery yet?" :)

Comment: And why didn't I?

Comment: @Jeff, of course that makes sense. I was more wondering as to why one of my questions would be bumped frequently for months while another has been completely ignored.

Comment: I double-checked the query and it's random. I did increase the threshold from LastActivityDate > 14 days old to LastActivityDate > 30 days old just in case -- this reduces the odds a question would be re-selected, at least.