# Community user does not bump questions that never had an answer

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, community-user, bump

One of the duties of the community user is to

> Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention

according to the Community user FAQ.

This seems to only happen for questions with non-upvoted answers, but not for questions without any answers at all. I did go through a large number of posts on two sites where I am a mod (so I can see deleted answers), and I found no examples where the community user bumped a post that never had any answers at all. I always thought that the community user was supposed to also bump entirely unanswered questions.

Is this a bug, or is this intentional and the description of the community user is simply misleading?

Comment: Side question: how do you see which posts Community has bumped?

Comment: @BilltheLizard perhaps [make that a Meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110177/is-there-any-way-to-see-which-posts-community-has-bumped) ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard The hard way, making a search for all unanswered questions and scanning it for questions last edited by community. Not exhaustive, but the best I can do with the regular search.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31480/152859 (can't vote to close due to bounty)

Comment: But I'll support feature request asking to change the current behavior, maybe let it bump based on other factors. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't see how this is a dupe, it does ask about a single question and not a specific pattern, and the answer from Jeff indicates that unanswered questions should be bumped, so this is actually a bug and not by design

Comment: @Mad "Question 2 has 19 views, no upvotes, no comments, **no answers** and has **never once been bumped**" and it's marked by design meaning the current design is indeed that questions with no answers are never bumped. Jeff response should explain why the design is this way, though I didn't quite get it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/155074):

> Note that the posts eligible for bumping have gone at least 30 days
>   with no activity, **have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring
>   more than that**, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be locked or
>   closed).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an unanswered old question bumped, you have to answer it. :)

If you're lucky, [you may get badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97455/248268)!